# Python csv to dictionary with first line as title

Tags: python, csv

I have a file file.csv with some data:

```
fn,ln,tel
john,doe,023322
jul,dap,024322
jab,sac,0485
```

I would like to have an array that I can access like this:

```
file = 'file.csv'
with open(file,'rU') as f: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

print reader[0].fn
```

So I would like that it prints the first name from the first record. Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

How can I get it done so that I don't need to keep the file opened and that I can play with my array. Btw, I don't need to write back in the csv file, I just need to use the data and for that, an array that I can modify would be best.

Comment: what output do you want a dict or an array? Also your error is not correct for your code supplied

Comment: Note that `reader[0]` wouldn't work in or out of the `with` statement. You'd get an `AttributeError` because a `reader` object has no `__getitem__` method. Also, `DictReader` rows are ordinary dictionaries, so `row.fn` does not work, you'd use `row['fn']`. You over-simplified something here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the reader *within the `with` block, not outside of it:

```
file = 'file.csv'
with open(file,'rU') as f: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    first_row = next(reader)
    print first_row['fn']
```

As soon as you move code outside the block, the `f` file object is *closed* and you cannot obtain rows from the reader anymore. This is kind of the point of the `with` statement.

If you want to have random access to all rows in the file, convert the reader to a list first:

```
file = 'file.csv'
with open(file,'rU') as f: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    all_rows = list(reader)

print all_rows[0]['fn']
```

The `list()` call will iterate over the `reader`, adding each result yielded to the list object until all rows are read. Make sure you have enough memory to hold all those rows.

Comment: I got that but how can I do to keep it outside then? I need to use this in different functions.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: good question, as `reader` doesn't support indexing at all. I think the OP over-simplified a `for` loop somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep, the code they are using is definitely not like the code in the question.